# Make Imp the default app on logging into Horde

Tags: horde, imp

After a user is logged into Horde (v5.2.22), he is taken to the portal dashboard. I wonder if it is possible to automatically take logged users to the Imp application (webmail), so that they do not have to do a click to see their email messages.

This is the portal dashboard. If the user clicks on any of the mail panels, he goes to the webmail application.

[image: Horde portal]

And this is the webmail app (Imp), that is where I would like logged users would be taken after a successful log in:

[image: Imp webmail]

Best wishes,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the folder where you have horde's prefs.php file, go ahead and create
a parallel file with these contents:

```
<?php
$_prefs['initial_application']['value'] = 'imp';
```

Note the "<?php" at the start of the file.  If this file already exists with some other content, then you just need the one line containing "initial_application"

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I added the $_prefs['initial_application']['value'] = 'imp'; to /etc/horde/horde/prefs.local.php and it did the trick.